# Original series episode with life forms in the earth communicating by saline streams?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

I web searched but can't find such an episode. Closest thing that comes to it is "Devil in the Dark".  In TNG, there is "Home Soil", but I could've sworn that this idea came up in the original series.

**Is there a TOS episode with life forms in the earth communicating by saline streams?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you're mis-remembering the TNG episode "[Home Soil](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/117.htm)"

> **LUISA:** *There is a very thin layer of highly saline water under the
>   sandy top soil. He was siphoning that off.*
>
> **CRUSHER:** *Perhaps somehow that saline water sustained them.*
>
> **DATA:** *It connected them.*
>
> **LUISA:** *I don't understand.*
>
> **CRUSHER:** *The microbrains may be like our own brain cells.
>   Individually, a cell has life but not intelligence. Yet **when
>   interconnected, their combined intelligence is formidable.***
>
> **DATA:** ***The saline fluid is their circuitry,*** and to prevent its loss,
>   they killed Malencon.

Comment: I just watched the TNG episode on Netflix before posting my question.  I'm trying to square that off with my foggy memory of a scene on the TOS bridge where they actually saw some subterranean image, and a vein of fluid seeping.